# Obtener coordenadas con click en google maps, angular 4,5,6

Tags: angular, google-maps

Necesito obtener las coordenadas del punto en google maps donde doy click, esto es con angular 4.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si es exactamente lo que estás preguntando, pero en mi caso, para mapas con angular, estoy usando Angular Maps (https://angular-maps.com/).

Y en el caso de tu consulta, en el HTML:

```
 <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" (mapClick)="getMapClick($event)" (mapReady)="mapReady($event)"></agm-map>
```

En el componente:

```
getMapClick(e) {
  console.log(e.coods.lat, e.coods.lng);
}
```

Espero que sea lo que estás buscando, cualquier cosa no dudes en volver a preguntar. Por cierto, te recomendaría leer las reglas de Stackoverflow para la formulación de preguntas.